# How to run MySQL query in Ansible

Tags: mysql, automation, ansible

I need to write an Ansible script to execute a SQL query in a MySQL database.

Here is what I tried. Can you please guide me.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - name: retrive data
     command: mysql -u root -h localhost dbname ansible --execute "select * from MyGuests"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `mysql_query` module in Ansible 2.10+. Please see the example below:

```
- name: Select query to test_db with named_args
  mysql_query:
  login_db: test_db
  query: SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = %(id_val)s AND story = %(story_val)s
  named_args:
    id_val: 1
    story_val: test
```

Please note the requirements to use this module:
PyMySQL (Python 2.7 and Python 3.X), or MySQLdb (Python 2.x)

For more information:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/modules/mysql_query_module.html (for the Ansible development version)

Comment: Worth mentioning this is available only from Ansible 2.10

Comment: Thanks Chen, I updated it to say it needs 2.10+.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query  is part of the community.mysql collection (version 2.1.0).

To install it use: ansible-galaxy collection install community.mysql.

To use it in a playbook, specify: community.mysql.mysql_query