# Ansible: How to execute ALTER statements on database with delay?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have generated a file with bunch of alter statements based on certain condition on cluster using Ansible task.

Here's the sample file content

```
alter table test1 with throttling = 0.0;
alter table test2 with throttling = 0.0;
alter table test3 with throttling = 0.0;
```

I want to login and execute these ALTER statements with a delay of 2 mins. I was able to achieve this with a shell script using `sleep` command by copying the shell script from Control Node and execute on Remote Node.

But the problem we noticed was we were unable to check if script executed properly or failed (like authentication failed to DB, etc.)

Can we perform the same task using Ansible module and execute them one by one with some delay?

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be more a requirement than a question. For better understanding it might be helpful to provide the shell script. Furthermore, what are the questions regarding the Ansible modules? Especially regarding the error handling "_we were unable to check if script executed properly or failed_".

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

> *Can we perform the same task using ansible module and execute them one by one with some delay?*

the short answer, yes, of course.

A slightly longer minimal example

```yaml
- name: Run queries against db test_db with pause
  community.mysql.mysql_query:
    login_db: test_db
    query: "ALTER TABLE test{{ item }} WITH throttling = 0.0;"
  loop: [1, 2, 3]
  loop_control:
    pause: 120 # seconds
```

**Further Documentation**

- [Community.Mysql - Modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/index.html#modules)
- [`mysql_query` module – Run MySQL queries](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/mysql_query_module.html)
- [Pausing with `loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#pausing-within-a-loop)
- [Extended loop variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables)

**Further Q&A**

- [How to run MySQL query in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61610908/6771046)
- [Ensuring a delay in an Ansible `loop`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53268242/6771046)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  i just shared few test table names for Stackoverflow but actual table names and count might vary depending on database.

`
alter table config with throttling=0.0
alter table pattern with throttling =0.0
`
is there a way i can send each line of file in loop?  similar to what we can do in bash
`
`for i in cat <file>;do
done`

Comment: A lot is possible in Ansible. I recommend to first review [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then you may edit your initial question and provide more details, information and description.

Comment: Regarding your question "_... similar to what we can do in bash `for i in cat <file>;do done `_", that is already what the here given answer is showing.